Vite hot reloading with XSLT?
I want to use XSLT to transform some XML into HTML at build time for my web app.
I have currently configured this as a script in package.json that runs the xslt3 (SaxonJS) CLI, but I'm not sure if this is the best way.
I'd like it if Vite's dev server could hot reload when I change the XML file, by re-running the transformation and then refreshing the browser.  Is there a way to set that up?
What I've Tried
I looked in Vite docs for configuration options related to hot reloading such as server.hmr but that seems more about the connection layer.
I found something called the HMR API, which maybe means I can write my own plugin to do this?  But I wonder if there's an easier way or someone has already written one.
I tried searching for Vite XSLT integration but didn't find a clear answer.

I don't know much about Vite but regarding SaxonJS, if the XSLT doesn't change, you can precompile it once with xslt3 -export to an SEF file and then you can run the XSLT transformation with client-side JavaScript using the SaxonJS API. I just throw that in in a comment, perhaps it helps for your use case to hot reload with Vite, perhaps not.

Update: I basically got what I'm looking for with entr:
echo foo.xml | entr npx xslt3 -xsl:transform.xsl -s:foo.xml -o:foo.html
